# Is there any possible way to retrieve the block time for those txs occurred before September 2020

Tags: transactions, block-time

I know that there is no block time for older transactions before September 2020. But is there any possible way to retrieve the missing block time, or to define when the transaction occurred?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Older solana blocks have no timestamp?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/9393/older-solana-blocks-have-no-timestamp)